# Can't install Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 8

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to install VS2010 on my new Windows 8 machine.  This is an install from an MSDN subscription and it installed fine on my Windows 7 machine.  But when I try on the new machine, I have to accept the EULA, and then it shows a messages that says:

> You have entered an invalid product key for this product.  The 25 character product key may be found on the media case or obtained online at: [some Microsoft page]

But this is really weird because **there's no place to enter the product key**, and it never asked for a key on Windows 7, which installed and worked fine.  So I think it may be a Windows 8 thing.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution I found online for your problem:

1. Find the setup\setup.sdb file in the Disk or Image.
2. Open this setup.sdb file in Notepad like program.
3. Find the  tag
   [Product Key]
   BD9TPWJD9XBWX4KQPWVY4GW9G
4. Replace this product  key by new key  either from any source or from

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/download

Under "REGISTER TO EXTEND YOUR TRIAL"

People say it helped.
Good Luck

Comment: This worked to let me enter my product code, and then I was able to enter the correct code and install.  Thanks!